# Comparing paths with special characters on Mac UTF-8

Tags: c, macos, utf-8, kernel-extension

We have a kext that checks if a path is a subdir of another path and does some magic if it is.

This all works fine as long we don't have special characters in our path (characters like `ë`)

We feed some working paths into the system by a helper application that can communicate with the kext.

I've isolated the problem to this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char* path = "/Users/user/test/tëst/test"; //Sent by the system
  char* wp = "/Users/user/test/tëst"; //Some path we claim to be ours

  size_t wp_len = strlen(wp);

  if (strncmp (wp,path,wp_len) == 0) //Check is path is a subpath
  {
    printf ("matched %s\n", path);
  }else {
    printf ("could not match\n");

  }
  return 0;
}
```

I've created a Gist, so the encoding does not go lost with the browser: https://gist.github.com/fvandepitte/ec28f4321a48061808d0095853af7bd7

Someone knows how i can check if `path` is a subpath of `wp` without losing too much performance (this code runs in the kernel)?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1173/_index.html

Answer (score 1):

I've copy/pasted the source straight from the browser into a file (test.c). It prints `could not match` for me.

If I dump the file using `od` this is what I see:

```
bash-3.2$ od -c test.c                                                     
0000000    #   i   n   c   l   u   d   e       <   s   t   d   i   o   .   
0000020    h   >  \n   #   i   n   c   l   u   d   e       <   s   t   r   
0000040    i   n   g   .   h   >  \n  \n   i   n   t       m   a   i   n   
0000060        (   )  \n   {  \n           c   h   a   r   *       p   a   
0000100    t   h       =       "   /   U   s   e   r   s   /   u   s   e   
0000120    r   /   t   e   s   t   /   t   ë  **   s   t   /   t   e   s   
0000140    t   "   ;       /   /   S   e   n   t       b   y       t   h   
0000160    e       s   y   s   t   e   m  \n           c   h   a   r   *   
0000200        w   p       =               "   /   U   s   e   r   s   /   
0000220    u   s   e   r   /   t   e   s   t   /   t   e    ̈  **   s   t   
0000240    "   ;       /   /   S   o   m   e       p   a   t   h       w
```

Notice that the tëst of `path` comes out as `t   ë  **   s   t`,
but the tëst of `wp` comes out as `t   e    ̈  **   s   t`, which is different: so `strncmp` will fail when comparing `ë` and `e`.

If I copy the tëst from `path` paste that into `wp`'s assignment then I get `matched /Users/user/test/tëst/test`, so `strncmp` seems to work fine.

I don't know these two strings differ like this, I can only assume that the two strings are using different encodings somehow. The `strncmp` function compares strings per byte, so `ë` and `e ̈` are considered different. If you want to use `strncmp`, then unfortunately there's no easy solution to this other than insuring that both strings use the same encoding.

FWIW - I'm running on macOS 10.12.1, with clang version Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)

**EDIT:** I've downloaded pathtest.cpp from your github link just to double-check things. I've run `od -c pathtest.cpp` and I see the same problem.

Comment: Thx for the info, I'll see what @n.m. came up with.

Comment: After further reading and having a "AHA"-moment, I can say that we have precomposed and decomposed characters. Somehow we store decomposed values in the kext and I think I can fix it where we store it.